# CheckBox in Collection view trying to get values

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, checkbox, uicollectionview

I have a collection View with an image, name and a checkbox. When I click submit I am trying to collect all the names in a list. I used breakpoints and notice the all my profiles are returned as Selected == false. I think there is a problem with my binding however I am a bit lost as to why.

My ProfileModel:

```
 public class Profile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    public string UserName { get; set; }       
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    private bool _Selected;
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _Selected; }
        set
        {
            _Selected = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
 public class ProfileViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        
    public ObservableCollection<Profile> source;
    public ObservableCollection<Profile> ProfileInfo { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Profile> EmptyProfileInfo
    {
        get => source;
        set
        {               
            {
                source = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EmptyProfileInfo));
            }
        }
    }
    
    public ProfileViewModel ()
    {
        EmptyProfileInfo = new ObservableCollection<Profile>();                   
    }
           
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My Xaml:

```
 <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding EmptyProfileInfo}" HeightRequest="200">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="10" RowDefinitions="80" ColumnDefinitions="120,60,60">
                            <Image Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               x:Name="Image"
                               Source="{Binding imageUrl}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Text="{Binding UserName}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               x:Name="labelpetname" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <CheckBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Profile.cs

```
private string CreateNameList()
    {
        List<string> NameList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var profile in ProfileViewModel.EmptyProfileInfo)
        {               
            if (profile.Selected)
            {
                NameList.Add(profile.UserName);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: is Profile.cs using the same instance of ProfileViewModel as the page?

Comment: Yes I am using the same instance

Comment: your bindings appear correct.  You can easily check this by putting a breakpoint or Writeline in the Selected setter

Comment: Hi, yes you were correct. I changed it to (BindingContext as ProfileViewModel).EmptyProfileInfo) and now it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your change on the UI to reflect onto your properties you need to set the binding mode as two way, so the UI communicates with the BindingContext by default this is set to one way

```
IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: interactive controls should default to two way binding

Comment: @Jason Is it? I didn't know that! When did that happen?

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#two-way-bindings.  Checkbox isn't explicitly mentioned, but this doc hasn't been updated since 2018